# A Pick Lemma like problem

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be analytic on the unit disc $D$ and bounded in modulus by $M$ there. I want to show that $|f'(z)|\le \frac{M}{1-|z|}$ for all $z\in D$.

I want to use Schwarz's lemma here after some suitable FLTs, as in the proof of Pick's lemma, but I haven't made progress. Does anyone have an idea?

Edited: Forgot a factor of $M$ in the inequality originally.

Comment: Is your map univalent?

Comment: I did not understand that condition to be a requirement for the problem, I can say.

Comment: Because in this case you have a better control.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Cauchy's formula.  We have that $f'(z) = \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{B(z,r)}{\frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^2}}d\zeta$, where $r$ is small enough so the ball $B(z,r)$ is contained inside the disk.   By the boundedness assumption, and using the standard bounds for the integral we get that $|f'(z)| \leq M(2\pi r)\frac{1}{2\pi r^2} = \frac{M}{r}$.  Now let $r \rightarrow 1-|z|$ and we are done.

Comment: That was very straightforward. Thanks.