# Question on analytic function in the unit disk satisfying Lipschitz condition of order $\alpha$

Tags: complex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, analytic-functions

The question is as follows:

> Let $0<\alpha<1$. Let $f(z)$ be analytic on $\mathbb{D}$. If $|f(z)-f(w)|\leq C|z-w|^{\alpha}$ for any $z,w\in\mathbb{D}$ and a constant $C$, then there exists a constant $A=A(C)<\infty$ such that $|f'(z)|\leq A(1-|z|)^{\alpha-1}$.

My first attempt was to use Schwarz-Pick. But then I realized that the function might not be bounded. Then I found an analogous question: [A Pick Lemma like problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188457/a-pick-lemma-like-problem?noredirect=1&lq=1). The solution uses Cauchy integral formula. I suppose the same method should be applied here, but I don't know how to proceed. Any hint will be appreciated.

Comment: Hints: 1. In the integral formula in the linked answer the numerator of the integrand can be replaced by $f(\zeta)-f(z)$ without changing the value of the integral. 2. The Lipschitz condition makes it possible to extend $f$ to a continuous function on the closed unit disk.

Comment: (the second hint in my previous comment is actually unnecessary, it shows that $f$ is bounded which isn't needed here)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the hint given by leoli1 in the comment, I can complete the answer:
\begin{equation}
|f'(z)|=|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w|=r}\dfrac{f(w)}{(w-z)^2}dw|
=|\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|w|=r}\dfrac{f(w)-f(z)}{(w-z)^2}dw|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|w|=r}\dfrac{|f(z)-f(w)|}{|z-w|^2}dw \leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|w|=r}\dfrac{C|z-w|^{\alpha}}{|z-w|^2}dw=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|w|=r}C|z-w|^{\alpha-2}dw\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|w|=r}C'r^{\alpha-2}dw=\frac{1}{2\pi}C'r^{\alpha-1}.
\end{equation}
Letting $r\rightarrow 1-|z|$, we are done.